# SQL with two subqueries - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables (tblAAA and tblBBB). I am trying to get a query that will sum the total from one column based on criteria from another column (1) and the sum of that same column based on different criteria from the same column I got the first criteria from (2). Then I need to do the same one more time from another table (3). The last thing I need to do is perform a calculation that will yield one result (3 + 1 - 2). Here is what I have so far that I got somewhere else tailored to my situation. It works but only on two of the above. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT tblAAA.ID, 
        tblAAA.Type, SUM(tblAAA.Amount), 
        SUM(tblBBB.CurTotal),
       (SUM(tblBBB.CurTotal)) - SUM(tblAAA.Amount)
FROM tblAAA INNER JOIN tblBBB ON tblAAA.ID = tblBBB.ID
GROUP BY tblAAA.ID, tblAAA.Type
HAVING tblAAA.ID=15 AND tblAAA.Type="Credit";

Table1
Type     Amount
Debit    15.00
Debit    15.00
Debit    10.00
Credit   7.00    
Credit   13.00

Table2
CurTotal
5.00
10.00
15.00

Expected Output (30.00 + 20.00 - 40.00)
10.00
```

Comment: this is all way too vague. Give us the table structures. Name the exact sums you want including column names. Also, this looks suspiciously like homework.

Comment: Try rephrasing your question. Give us some context - some data, expected output etc. Read [How to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I really thought I did. I don't know what else to include. I want to get an output of one value. Example: 1 table with Debit/Credit column. I want the sum of all credits and the sum of all debits. Then I want the sum from a different table and column from which I will add the credits and subtract the debits. Both tables are junction tables. I'll try to edit. I hope that helps!